# Exporting SQL to Excel (xlsx) using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, unicode, ssis

I'm an SSIS noob (less than a week experience) so please bear with me.
I am running a stored procedure to export its result to an Excel file.

From my research I have found that SSIS's Excel Destination does not play nicely with .xlsx files (can't be xls since I have more than the ~65K rows in the result), but I found that I can use a OLE DB Destination to write to an excel file.

The issue I am seeing is an error message that occurs on run that says:

```
OLE DB Destination [212]] Error: 
An error occurred while setting up a binding for the "Main Job Notes" column. 
The binding status was "DT_NTEXT"."
```

The fields that are erroring are coming in as Text Streams ([DT_TEXT]), and since I was getting an error around not being able to convert between unicode and non-unicode, I use a Data Conversion to transform it into a Unicode text stream ([DT_NTEXT])

If it helps at all, my setup is as follows:

[image]

Any help would be amazing. Thank you.

Comment: I have seen JET provider really confound SSIS/Excel when text data exceeds 255 characters -- which is implied to be the case if you're using DT_NTEXT.  Try forcing the length to <255 as a test to see if that's your problem.  If so, you'll have to decide if you want to live with the truncation, or maybe just export to CSV or flat file (which I often find is the best route).

Comment: @Greenspark Yeah a couple of those fields are VARCHAR(max). And one of them when pulled straight from SQL management studio has around 80,000 characters. So some truncation is bound to happen. I'll test the 255 characters and report back.

Comment: @Greenspark alright, truncating works. Now my issue is that the export is not conserving my template format.

Comment: what kind of template are you using, @npiani?

Comment: @Greenspark I have an xlsx file with only column headers in which I have set the column formats. On run, I replace my file with the template and insert the data into it. No matter what I've done, the values are formatted as "General", and not as I set in the template.

Comment: I got around this by writing a C# console app with the EPPlus extended library module, then calling it with TSQL. If you need any guidance on it or source code/releases then hit me up with an email.

Comment: Is there a way to use DT_TEXT in the destination column (i.e avoid truncating?) I also tried with Excel Destination task and it will only accept DT_WSTR 255 at the most :/ (or so it seems)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider doing this using a script component, keep in mind that when in data flow task you cannot debug directly but you can use mbox snipped to check results. Also keep in mind that excel will always try to suppose your column data types automatically, for example when you try to import a file from excel that one of its columns starts with a number but in the row 3455 there's a character, it will import the column as a number and you will lose the char value, you will find it as null in your database.

I will give you some code to construct the file you need programmatically, maybe it can give you an idea. (This example reads a file as one column, then it will split in as if you chose fixed with delimited values in excel and will output in a csv file.

```
/* Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Script Component
*  Write scripts using Microsoft Visual C# 2008.
*  ScriptMain is the entry point class of the script.*/

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    #region Variables
    private string _jumexDailyData;
    private string[] _jumexValues;
    private string[] _jumexWidthValues;      
    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ScriptMain()
    {        
        this._jumexValues = new string[22];        
    }

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();
        /*
          Add your code here for preprocessing or remove if not needed
        */
    }

    public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();
        /*
          Add your code here for postprocessing or remove if not needed
          You can set read/write variables here, for example:
          Variables.MyIntVar = 100
        */
    }

    public override void JumexDailyData_ProcessInput(JumexDailyDataBuffer Buffer)
    {        
        while (Buffer.NextRow())
            JumexDailyData_ProcessInputRow(Buffer);        
    }

    public override void JumexDailyData_ProcessInputRow(JumexDailyDataBuffer Row)
    {
        this._jumexDailyData = Row.JumexDailyData;
        if (this._jumexDailyData != null)
        {
            this._jumexWidthValues = this.Variables.JUMEXLOADSALESATTACHMENTFILEWIDTHVALUES.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (this._jumexWidthValues != null && this._jumexWidthValues.Count() > 0)
                for (int i = 0; i < this._jumexWidthValues.Count(); i++)
                {
                    this._jumexValues[i] = this._jumexDailyData.Substring(0, int.Parse(this._jumexWidthValues[i])).Trim();
                    this._jumexDailyData = this._jumexDailyData.Substring(int.Parse(this._jumexWidthValues[i]), (this._jumexDailyData.Length - int.Parse(this._jumexWidthValues[i])));
                }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._jumexValues[3].Trim()) == false &&
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._jumexValues[17].Trim()) == false &&
                !this._jumexValues[3].Contains("---") &&
                !this._jumexValues[17].Contains("---") &&
                !this._jumexValues[3].Trim().ToUpper().Contains("FACTURA") &&
                !this._jumexValues[17].Trim().ToUpper().Contains("PEDIDO"))                
                using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(this.Variables.JUMEXFULLQUALIFIEDLOADSALESATTACHMENTFILENAME.Replace(".TXT", ".CSV"), true, Encoding.Default))
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(string.Join("|", this._jumexValues));
                }
        }        
    }

}
```